# A reasonable way to organize selectors?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to React/Redux and I have a question that I couldn't find the answer anywhere else.

In your containers, you have to grab the props you need from the `redux` state. And obviously it's a bad idea to just destructure the state inside `mapStateToProps`, containers shouldn't know about the state shape.

So we have `selectors`. `Selectors` are good, they can be reused or composed and containers can just use `selectors` to get the data that they need without having to know how the state is structured, but I still can't find a reasonable way to organize my selectors.

The thing is that state shape might change in the future, and in that case we have to update our `selectors`, you don't want to get incorrect data, or even worse, getting `runtime errors`.

- How do you know which selectors need to be updated after updating the state tree?

Dan Abramov has a course on egghead (which helped me get started with `redux`, awesome course) and what he does is basically exporting `selectors` with related reducers ([you can watch the video here](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers) or [the code here](https://github.com/gaearon/todos/blob/27-updating-data-on-the-server/src/reducers/index.js)), which makes sense, because then when you update a `reducer`, you know that you just need to update the related `selectors` (which are in the same file).

But as you can see in the code, everything has to go through the root reducer, and not just that, if I need to grab some data in a `"leaf reducer"`, I have to create `selectors` in that `reducer`, `root reducer` and all the intermediate `reducers`, which doesn't seem like a good idea.

- So how do you organize your `selectors`?

Answer (score 1):

The state of my app depends on the topic and has a hyrarchical form like

```
state
- ui
  - topic1
    - setting1
    - setting2
  - topic2
    - setting1
    - setting2
- user
  - name
  - role
- items
  - currentlySelectedItem
  - listOfAllItems
```

I'm using https://github.com/reactjs/reselect to create effitient and composable selectors. In my file structure you'll find the selectors ordered in a similar way:

```
folder1
folder2
redux-actions
redux-reducers
redux-selectors
- uiSelectors.js
- userSelectors.js
- itemsSelectors.js
...
```

The file uiSelectors.js contains the selectors for `state.ui`. If I feel like, I add a file `uiTopic1Selectors.js`. Of course, this could become confusing if you have a realy big app but for me it works. Btw: I use a similar structure for my reducers.

When I change the state, I'll have to change some selectors. Because my selectors are composable, I usually don't have to change too much.

The stateToProps function I usually place in the file of the page itself or a `page1Selector.js` file in the page folder.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I still have a concern. If you decide to do a big refactor, make a lot of changes on your state tree, then it's quite likely that you'll run into runtime errors, right?

Comment: I think using composable selectors and reducers keeps your program agile. The next step of using them is to test it. I recommend writing unit tests for selectors and reducers. The input and output of the tests is in JSON format which is easy testable and you have a good overview. Testing will help you to prevent runtime errors. I use https://jasmine.github.io/ for testing.